# Spring webClient generate NullPointException after going through the filter

Tags: spring, webclient, spring-webflux

I want to do exception handling. When StatusCode 200, but not the desired body.

To make the processing global I am using filter.

below is the code.

```java
public WebClient webClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(response -> {

                // statusCode 400 || 500
                if (response.statusCode().isError()) {
                    return response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                            .flatMap(body ->
                                    Mono.error(new ExternalClientException(body))
                                    )
                            );
                }

                // statusCode 200
                return  response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .flatMap(body -> {
                            if (YanoljaConstants.EMPTY_BODY.contains(body)) {
                                return Mono.error(new ExternalClientException(body))
                                        .cast(ClientResponse.class);
                            }
                            return Mono.just(response); // normal
                        });
            }))
            .build();
}
```

And the actual client code is shown below.

```java
public Foo getPlace(int no) {
    return Objects.requireNonNull(contentsApiV2Client.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/path").build(no))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Foo>() {
            })
            .block());
}
```

**When using this, NullPointerException occurs when responding normally after going through the filter(`return Mono#just(response)`).**

I want clear this issue.

For reference, the below code works normally.

```java
public WebClient webClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(response -> {
                // statusCode 400 || 500
                if (response.statusCode().isError()) {
                    return response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                            .flatMap(body ->
                                    Mono.error(new ExternalClientException(body))
                                    )
                            );
                }
                return Mono.just(response); // normal
            }))
            .build();
}
```

Thank you. waiting for your answer!

---

Solve!

```java
public WebClient webClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(response -> {

                // statusCode 400 || 500
                if (response.statusCode().isError()) {
                    return response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                            .flatMap(body ->
                                    Mono.error(new ExternalClientException(body))
                                    )
                            );
                }

                // statusCode 200
                return  response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .flatMap(body -> {
                            if (YanoljaConstants.EMPTY_BODY.contains(body)) {
                                return Mono.error(new ExternalClientException(body))
                                        .cast(ClientResponse.class);
                            }
                            return Mono.just(ClientResponse.create(HttpStatus.OK)
                                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
                                        .body(body)
                                        .build()); // normal
                        });
            }))
            .build();
}
```

I realized that running the monoTobody method consumes it and the value disappears. So I solved it by creating a new ClientResponse.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the full error? I think it is happening because the `response` is already read in `bodyToMono` process.  That can be causing the response is null. but this is a wild guess. it will be helpful if you post the full error

Comment: thank you!, you were right!
I realized that running the monoTobody method consumes it and the value disappears. So I solved it by creating a new ClientResponse.

Comment: That's great. Great to know it helped